# Cannot determine difference in fonts

Tags: css, fonts

I am working on a website where I would like the paragraphs and h2 tags to have the same appearance visually.

I have looked through the code so many times but cannot see why they appear (ever so slightly) different.

I am hoping a fresh pair of eyes may be able to spot it. I want the h2 tag to be styled the same as the paragraphs.

The website is [here.](http://goo.gl/JAUGwD)

Comment: `letter-spacing: -1px` , you should apply this to the `p` element

Answer (score 0):

It's about CSS trick.
For example:

```
<style>
    body {
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:1.100;
        font-family:arial;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:300;
        line-height:1.100;
        display:inline;
        font-family:arial;
    }
</style>

we need <h2>our product</h2>
```

The focus you should take notice is the size of font, font-weight and display. Hoe this helps

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/7g3rLubf/1/)**

If you need the h2 tag inside the p tag 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alicera/7g3rLubf/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
h2{
padding-bottom: 5px;
color: #808080;
**letter-spacing: -1px;**
line-height: 1em;
font-weight: normal;}
```

have letter-spacing: -1px; for p element and it will appear the same

Answer (score 0):

Your header tags have a letter spacing of -1px (defined in style.css on line 56):

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { padding-bottom: 5px; color: #808080; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1em; font-weight: normal; }
```

I was able to determine this using Chrome's developer tools by inspecting the h2 and the p tags in the Elements panel, and looking through the computed styles in the Styles tab to see what's different about them. I noticed the h2 has letter-spacing, whereas the p does not:

[image]